# how break 1row into 2row at tablet view (width=767px) in bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating wordpress theme using bootstrap.

I have a file with 3 col and it shows 4 post per row, its looking good for laptop view.

The problem is at `767px width`. it show one post per row means one post use one row and 4post uses 4rows.

is there anyway in bootstrap that at tablet view 4post show in 2 rows not in 4 rows??? @media queries not handling this

**current at 767px-->  4 posts = 4 row**

**required at 767px-->  4 posts = 2 row**

**content.php**

```
  <div <?php post_class( 'custom-col col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3' ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

         <div class="single-post">     
          div class="post-thumb" > 
               <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail  ( 'large', array(
                  'class' => 'img-responsive' 
                ) ); ?> </a>
         </div>            
        <div class="post-title">
             <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

 <?php $item_number++;
 if( $item_number % 4 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 1 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
 if( $item_number % 4 == 0 ) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>'; 
 ?>
```

Comment: did you try karate chopping it, that's what I usually do.?  Seriously, you'd have to conditionally output the content blocks, I would think the clearfix and mod would do that?

Comment: at 767px width two post show per row not 1.. i don,t have more knowledge about php.. plz fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change this `col-xs-3` to this  `col-xs-6`

see [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed) about Grid System

below is a basic demo

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 25% wide on desktop -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">.col-xs-6 .col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">.col-xs-6 .col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">.col-xs-6 .col-md-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see updated answer, and please provide generated html instead backended html